Autofill from LastPass Not Working for Password Inputs in React Native App
Our customers have complained that the autofill integration of LastPass does not work for the password input in our React Native app on Android. We tried all feasible configurations of the input field as well as different settings in LastPass but were unable to resolve the issue.
Strangely, the problem only occurs with the password input, not the username input. Additionally, other autofill integrations, such as those from Google or Microsoft Authenticator, have no problem filling the password input.
This suggests there may be a bug in how the LastPass autofill integration identifies password inputs.
Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Verify that your password input field is properly configured with the correct attributes. Common attributes that might affect autofill are:
<TextInput
  secureTextEntry={true}
  autoCompleteType="password" // Deprecated, use textContentType on iOS
  textContentType="password" // For iOS
  accessibilityLabel="Password" // Helpful for accessibility services
  accessibilityHint="Input field for your password" // Helpful for accessibility services
/>

Try experimenting with different combinations of secureTextEntry, autoCompleteType, and textContentType attributes. Sometimes, small tweaks in these attributes can affect how different services interact with the input fields.
Search LastPass forums or support for any known issues related to autofill with React Native apps or specifically on Android. It's possible that this is a known issue that they are working on resolving.
Ensure that both the LastPass app and your app's dependencies are up to date. Autofill services can be sensitive to versions and recent updates might have resolved the issue.

Thanks for the reply. We tried various configurations, specifically we tried to configure the input according to the React Native docs.
